# Bookmarklet not loading on Chrome and FireFox.

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, firefox, bookmarklet

Created a bookmarklet that opens up a menu on any website. However it does not work in Chrome and Firexfox. Only works in Safari. Anyone have any ideas on how I can fix this?

Here is what the bookmarklet link looks like. I would have posted the rest of the .js code but  it was to long for this form. Please help.

```
<a href="javascript:(function(){document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('script')).src='http://www.poolit.me/bookmarklet/poolapp.js';})();">Run Bookmarklet</a>
```

Comment: Expand on "does not work". Plugging in that link using Chrome pulls up a hamburger icon in my top left. So the link itself seems to work. Have you checked the console for errors?

Comment: Perchance the page you are using it on is https?

Comment: top left icon that pops up should open to a menu when clicked. not https pages. No errors in console either.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your bookmarklet is in violation of the site you are testing this on CSP. If I run the bookmarklet on google.com it says this in the console "Content-Security-Policy: The page’s settings observed the loading of a resource at inline (“script-src”)."